# Composability Example of Software Transactional Memory

Tags: haskell, clojure, stm

One of the major advantages of software transactional memory that always gets mentioned is composability and modularity.  Different fragments can be combined to produce larger components.  In lock-based programs, this is often not the case.

I am looking for a simple example illustrating this with actual code.  I'd prefer an example in Clojure, but Haskell is fine too.  Bonus points if the example also exhibits some lock-based code which can't be composed easily.

Comment: Interesting, but sounds more like a StackOverflow question to me.

Comment: This question has been asked there 4 minutes later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518546/software-transactional-memory-composability-example Would someone migrate and merge this question (if possible)?

Comment: Yeah after I posted it here, I realized it would probably be better on Stackoverflow.  If someone can merge it, thats fine with me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you have some bank accounts:

```
(def accounts 
 [(ref 0) 
  (ref 10) 
  (ref 20) 
  (ref 30)])
```

And a atomic "transfer" function:

```
(defn transfer [src-account dest-account amount]
  (dosync
    (alter dest-account + amount)
    (alter src-account - amount)))
```

Which works as follows:

```
(transfer (accounts 1) (accounts 0) 5)

(map deref accounts)
=> (5 5 20 30)
```

You can then easily compose the transfer function to create a higher level transaction, for example transferring from multiple accounts:

```
(defn transfer-from-all [src-accounts dest-account amount]
  (dosync
    (doseq [src src-accounts] 
      (transfer src dest-account amount))))

(transfer-from-all 
  [(accounts 0) (accounts 1) (accounts 2)] 
  (accounts 3) 
  5)

(map deref accounts)
=> (0 0 15 45)
```

Note that all of the multiple transfers happened in a single, combined transaction, i.e. it was possible to "compose" the smaller transactions.

To do this with locks would get complicated very quickly: assuming the accounts needed to be individually locked then you'd need to do something like establishing a protocol on lock acquisition order in order to avoid deadlocks. It's very easy to make a hard-to-detect mistake. STM saves you from all this pain.